# Python escape character mixed with backslash n for newline

Tags: python

I have a function in python which return a huge text table in a neat format.
My output has multiple `\n` an `\t`. 
I can print out the output and it would have preserved the table format. However, in a python interactive window,I want to call the function and not store it the output but display it on console screen.
What I see is `\\n` instead of `\n`.
I understand that \ is an escape character.But what do I do make my python interactively handle the formatting.
eg. for descriptive purpose only

```
def print_table():
    return table;

>>> print_table() #is there anything I can do here to have neat display
>>> r0c0 r0c1 \nr1c0 r1c1 
>>> print (print_table())
>>> r0c0 r0c1
    r1c0 r1c1
```

I am using Python3.6

Comment: `#is there anything I can do here to have neat display` No. That's just how the `__repr__` works. Newlines are shown as is.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is there a way I can suppress my output of a function. I will then display table from within function and also return the table.

Comment: Don't use a REPL...

Comment: You're using what is essentially a debug output, don't expect pretty formatting. Use `print` and be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pretty printer?

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(print_table)
```

Comment: Even a normal print is working fine. I just do not want to print and let the Python shell display from the return type

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result in a variable

```
>>> def print_table():
>>>    return table

>>> my_table = print_table() 
>>> print(my_table)
>>> r0c0 r0c1
    r1c0 r1c1
```